# How can I reduce/eliminate photo tag spam in my facebook news feed?

Tags: facebook, photos, facebook-tags

I have one friend in particular who will be regularly tagged in photos such that he will show up in my news feed with an update like "xyz was tagged in SomeBusinessPages photo".  The thing is my friend won't even be in the picture.  This happens frequently for this friend and I'm pretty sure it's tag spam.

Ideally I'd like to still receive notification of legitimate photo tags of my friend while filtering out this spam.  How can I do this?  It tends to be one user (actually a business page) that is tagging my friend in this spammy way.  I have not "liked" the page, perhaps there's a way just to block tags by the page?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the safe and free "**FB Purity**" browser extension's custom "Text Filter" function to accomplish this task.

First get FB Purity here: http://fbpurity.com

Then setup a custom text filter.
if the guys name was "joe bloggs"
then you would add a custom text filter of
"**Joe Bloggs was tagged in**"
though you need to leave the quotes out
and that will filter out any posts featuring the text "Joe Bloggs was tagged in"
which should accomplish what you requested.

Update, facebook have also started adding "mentioned in" as an alternative way of describing being "tagged in" a post, so you should add a filter like above, but replacing the words "tagged in" with "mentioned in"